solana-test-validator not working. (tried the approach in the similar question) and logging a different error
As stated in the docs, I have succesfully installed, cargo rust and all the required dependencies, However I am unable to run the test validator, this is the error logged,
Error: failed to start faucet: Unable to bind faucet to 0.0.0.0:9900, check the address is not already in use: Address already in use (os error 98)
Just to verify if solana cli has been installed properly, I tested airdroping SOL as well, and it worked just fine, Any possible way to fix this?


lsof -i :9000
kill -9 <process id>


What is the process id here?

It's PID in the lsof command.
